# PHP mysql_query - Get row of current week with current date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table as follows:

```
week    start_date  end date
1   2011-04-25  2011-05-01
2   2011-05-02  2011-05-08
3   2011-05-09  2011-05-15
```

I would like to run a query to get the week number when the current date is between the start_date and end_date of a specified week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT week
FROM table_name
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

**CURRENT_DATE()** is synonyms for **CURDATE()**.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT week FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE CURDATE() BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

Comment: holy cow, why have I not see `BETWEEN` before?. Is `date(now())` preferable to `CURRENT_DATE` for some reason?

Comment: This worked perfect!! Thank You! I did not know that BETWEEN existed.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Good luck @Prince.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple:

```
SELECT week FROM my_table WHERE CURRENT_DATE > start_date AND CURRENT_DATE <= end_date
```